# No me funcionan las tablas hechas en MySQL sobre Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

/* Drop Tables */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SE_COMPONE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ARTICULO;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PEDIDO;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CLIENTE;




/* Create Tables */

CREATE TABLE ARTICULO
(
    num_serie numeric NOT NULL,
    id_articulo numeric,
    nombre_articulo varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (num_serie),
    UNIQUE (num_serie)
);


CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
    dni varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    nombre_cliente varchar(40),
    apellidos varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (dni),
    UNIQUE (dni)
);


CREATE TABLE PEDIDO
(
    fecha datetime NOT NULL,
    id_pedido numeric,
    nombre_pedido varchar(100),
    dni varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (fecha),
    UNIQUE (fecha),
    UNIQUE (dni)
);


CREATE TABLE SE_COMPONE
(
    fecha datetime NOT NULL,
    num_serie numeric NOT NULL,
    cantidad numeric,
    peso double,
    caducidad datetime,
    UNIQUE (fecha),
    UNIQUE (num_serie)
);



/* Create Foreign Keys */

ALTER TABLE SE_COMPONE
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (num_serie)
    REFERENCES ARTICULO (num_serie)
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
;


ALTER TABLE PEDIDO
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (dni)
    REFERENCES CLIENTE (dni)
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
;


ALTER TABLE SE_COMPONE
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (fecha)
    REFERENCES PEDIDO (fecha)
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
;
```

## Me da los siguientes errores:

> Mens. 195, Nivel 15, Estado 7, Línea 2 'SESSION' no es un opción SET
>   reconocido. Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 53 Sintaxis
>   incorrecta cerca de ','. Mens. 156, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 66
>   Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'RESTRICT'. Mens. 156,
>   Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 74 Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra
>   clave 'RESTRICT'. Mens. 156, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 82 Sintaxis
>   incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'RESTRICT'.

Comment: Tu pregunta da la impresión que esperas que los scripts de MySQL siempre funcionen tal cual en SQL Server. Esto no es el caso. Se trata de 2 bases de datos diferentes, cada uno con sus peculiaridades. Lo correcto es tomar el tiempo de aprender la sintaxis de cada una y ajustar los scripts en consecuencia.

Comment: Vale, gracias @sstan. Hace mucho que no manejaba MySQL y pues no había chance, entonces necesitaba ayuda, chamako y pues claro eso haré mejoraré.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pesar de que tanto MySql como SQL Server utilizan SQL como lenguaje tienen sus diferencias en cuanto a sintaxis, en tu caso, solo se requieren algunos ajustes para que tu *script* funcione en SQL Server.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
/* Drop Tables */
IF OBJECT_ID('SE_COMPONE', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE SE_COMPONE;

IF OBJECT_ID('ARTICULO', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ARTICULO;

IF OBJECT_ID('PEDIDO', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE PEDIDO;

IF OBJECT_ID('CLIENTE', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE CLIENTE;

/* Create Tables */

CREATE TABLE ARTICULO
(
    num_serie numeric NOT NULL,
    id_articulo numeric,
    nombre_articulo varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (num_serie),
    UNIQUE (num_serie)
);

CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
    dni varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    nombre_cliente varchar(40),
    apellidos varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (dni),
    UNIQUE (dni)
);


CREATE TABLE PEDIDO
(
    fecha datetime NOT NULL,
    id_pedido numeric,
    nombre_pedido varchar(100),
    dni varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (fecha),
    UNIQUE (fecha),
    UNIQUE (dni)
);

CREATE TABLE SE_COMPONE
(
    fecha datetime NOT NULL,
    num_serie numeric NOT NULL,
    cantidad numeric,
    peso float,
    caducidad datetime,
    UNIQUE (fecha),
    UNIQUE (num_serie)
);

/* Create Foreign Keys */
ALTER TABLE SE_COMPONE
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (num_serie)
    REFERENCES ARTICULO (num_serie);

ALTER TABLE PEDIDO
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (dni)
    REFERENCES CLIENTE (dni);

ALTER TABLE SE_COMPONE
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (fecha)
    REFERENCES PEDIDO (fecha);

COMMIT
```

Nota: en **SQL Server** no tengo el conocimiento de alguna sentencia que realice una tarea similar al `RESTRICT` de MySql, si alguien llegase a complementar esta respuesta cualquier comentario es bienvenido. Mientras tanto, tu `script` ya es funcional en SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Mas que no te funcionen es que SQL Server no reconoce la sentencia RESTRICT pues tienes que especificar que es lo que quieres hacer, por ejemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE EmpEducation
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EmpEducation_Employees]
FOREIGN KEY (empno)REFERENCES employees(empno)
DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
GO
```

[Aqui](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2365/sql-server-foreign-key-update-and-delete-rules/) te dejo una liga que puede ayudarte un poco mas, espero te sea de ayuda.